# Plots in DT table

Tags: r, shiny

In the below application, the column e has some plots. But when you open the application it does not show. But when you click on any of the column headers, you see the plots in column e. Why is that so? Can we not have by default?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(glue)
library(dplyr)

asd1 <- data.frame(a = c(3,4,5,6), b = c("A","B","C","D"))
asd_fun <- function(x){as.vector(asd1$b)}

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("do", "select", choices = sapply(asd1$a, asd_fun)),
  selectInput("do1", "select1", choices = c("a" = 50,"b" = 100)),
  dataTableOutput("graph1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   
  # a1 <- 3
  
 
  
    output$graph1 <- renderDataTable({
      df_1 <- data.frame(a = c(50,100,150), b= c(860,1600,300), c = c(1140, 1700, 700),
                         d= c(960,1700,400), x = c(1130, 1100, 800),
                         y= c(160,700,300), z = c(130, 100, 300))
      
      df1 <-  df_1 %>% filter(a %in% input$do1) %>% mutate(bc = paste0(b, ",", c), dx = paste0(d, ",", x), yz = paste0(y, ",", z), e =  c(glue::glue(HTML('
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart{a}" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>

<script>
var xValues = [1,3];

new Chart("myChart{a}", {{
  type: "line",
  data: {{
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{{ 
      data: [{bc}],
      borderColor: "red",
      fill: false
    }}, {{ 
      data: [{dx}],
      borderColor: "green",
      fill: false
    }}, {{ 
      data: [{yz}],
      borderColor: "blue",
      fill: false
    }}]
  }},
  options: {{
    legend: {{display: false}}
  }}
}});
</script>
'))))
      
      datatable(df1, escape = F,rownames = F,selection = 'none', options = list(autowidth = FALSE))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Why is that so? Can we not have by default?

Comment: The issue here is probably that the chart is created before the table is rendered. I'd suggest you try `setTimeout()` to change the execution order. Or you switch to `library(reactable)` where embedded plots work out of the box. See [this section from the documentation](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#embedding-html-widgets).

Comment: Can you share an example of setTimeout(). I have not used yet :)